# What's the right site for hardware (Mac) questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where do questions along the lines of "how do I get my scanner (model number here) to work over the network with the latest OS X ?" (and similar questions) go?

(Obviously, they don't go on Stack Overflow.)

Is there a master list somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [master list](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

And the correct site could well be [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) - as [they say](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Ask Different is for Apple enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about ...

- Apple hardware
- Apple software
- other Apple products or services
- third-party hardware and software for Apple products

> 

and it is not about ...

> 

- Apple Developer Programs or iTunes Connect (including iAd and the iBookstore)
- programming, with the exception of AppleScript and Automator
- installing or using Apple operating systems on non-Apple hardware
- a shopping or buying recommendation for hardware
- pre-release or beta software
- obtaining or using pirated software or media

> 

... then you're in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: I still don't like the overlap between Super User and the above specific site...

Comment: @Arjan Ash a bash question - it is on topic on SO, SuperUser,   Unix & Linux and AskDifferent. If you are Ubuntu replace Ask Different by Ubuntu There is not one correct place for all questions sometimes there are several sites.

Comment: @mmmmmm indeed, and 8 years later, I _stil_ don't like that overlap very much. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[Super User](https://superuser.com/) is the most likely site - it is for general computing questions.

From the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
> - personal and home computer networking